# Why does my ajaxForm call send all forms on the page, rather than just the one I want?

Tags: jquery, forms

Good day.

When I use the following code, it sends all forms on the page, instead of just the one form I specified.

```
$('.imagetemp').on('change',function(){

var id = this.id;
var arr = id.split('upload');
var count = arr[1];

var form = '#imagetempform' + count;

$("form").ajaxForm(
...
...
...
```

Tell me please how to send just one form?

Comment: Please see my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17084096/1317805). :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `form` is a variable, you need to change:

```js
$("form")
```

To:

```js
$(form)
```

Otherwise you're referencing all form elements on the page as a variable wrapped in quotes is no longer a variable - it's a string, which `$()` interprets as a jQuery selector.

Refer to [jQuery's Element Selector ("element")](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) documentation for more info.

---

**Edit:** (from edited question):

> P.S.: $(form).ajax() not work test this you can see here http://testwork.ru/10006/template1.php (before image click on button 'выбрать')...

This is because your forms have no IDs.

```html
<form name="imagetempform1" class="..." ... >...</form>
```

`#` is used to select IDs. You can either add the IDs in:

```
<form name="imagetempform1" id="imagetempform1" class="..." ... >...</form>
```

Or you can change your selector to select the name instead with:

```js
var form = "[name='imagetempform" + count + "']";
```

Comment: @AlexN your forms don't have IDs, that is why. `#` is used to select IDs. You can change your selector to `var form = "[name='imagetempform" + count + "']";` to select the `name` instead.

Comment: @AlexN that looks like it should work to me. Is your server picking up the correct values?

Comment: yes you are right) but i asked other- i think that script not work, but i not update file.. thanks =)

Answer (score 3):

```
var form = '#imagetempform' + count;

$("form").ajaxForm(

Here you have assigned the form id in the form variable

so

$("form").ajaxForm( will be

$(form).ajaxForm(
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the double quotations:

```
$(form).ajaxForm(
```